# How to get state changed value after widget build?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have simple application where I work with user location. On first app open I will ask from user to allow location and then save to var. But when I try check inside widget location allow status it is return old value instance of changed value.

**Code**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yandex_mapkit/yandex_mapkit.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class PlacesListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _Map();
  }
}

class _Map extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapState createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<_Map> {
  YandexMapController controller;
  PermissionStatus _permissionStatus = PermissionStatus.undetermined;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _requestPermission();
  }

  Future<void> _requestPermission() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissions =
        await [Permission.location].request();
    setState(() {
      _permissionStatus = permissions[Permission.location];
    });
  }

  void _showMessage(BuildContext context, Text text) {
    final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context);
    scaffold.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: text,
        action: SnackBarAction(
            label: 'OK', onPressed: scaffold.hideCurrentSnackBar),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App Name'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Text('App Content'),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              if (_permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
                await Future.wait([
                  controller.moveToUser(),
                  controller.showUserLayer(
                    iconName: 'lib/assets/arrow.png',
                    arrowName: 'lib/assets/user_location1.png',
                    accuracyCircleFillColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5),
                  )
                ]);
              } else {
                _showMessage(context, const Text('Permission Denied'));
              }
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.place, color: Colors.white),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            heroTag: 'showUserLocation',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using `FloatingActionButton` I tried check `Permission` status in my code. But my var `_permissionStatus` doesn't updated when user allowed location. How to fix this problem and get changed value from state?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/location
and then you can read the permission status:

```
Location location = new Location();
PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
_permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
  _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    return;
  }
}
```

another way:

```
    location.hasPermision().then(PermissionStatus status){
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied){
    location.requestPermission().then((PermissionStatus requestStatus){
     // save the value 
    }
   );
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know when user grand the permission then you know it, you must use the wrap your widget with FocusScope like this:

first define this:

```
final _focusNode = FocusScopeNode();
```

then wrap it with this:

```
return FocusScope(
      node: _focusNode,
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
         _requestPermission();
        },.....
```

Comment: Which my widget I must wrap with `FocusScope` in my code? @mam_65

Comment: Its better wrap with `Scaffold` ,but every where did think needed ,you can use it.